# How to display facebook profile picture and name of my site visiter using PHP(without authenticating)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just want to display the username and profile picture of my blog visiter near the commenting area.I want to do without any authenticating with FB,Is there any way to do this ?? Am i totally wrong ??

Comment: Sorry for my poor language :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing it without the user authenticating. Getting the name and profile pic from FB requires authentication. The user must give you permission to access their information via the FB SDK.

You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/